# Why does my app crash when i click a certain button?

Tags: java, android, string, crash, int

Hello everyone so i'm pretty new to Java and this code below will surely prove it.
I'd greatly appreciate any tip upon where i've gone wrong, thanks!

I'm trying to create a simple app that displays a random quote, and gives the chance to guess who said it.

Pretty sure the main issue has to do with --->  if (guessNameInt == whoSaidItInt) 
because it only crashes when i click the button which enables the tryLuck if statement.

Heres my code below

```
int randomNum;
String whoSaidIt;

// quotes and numbers
public void randomRick(View view) {
    if (randomNum == 0) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Life is effort and I'll stop when I die!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        whoSaidIt = "Jerry";
    }

    if (randomNum == 1) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Well look where being smart got you.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        whoSaidIt = "Jerry";
    }

    if (randomNum == 2) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ohh yea, you gotta get schwifty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        whoSaidIt = "Rick";

    }

}

public void tryLuck(View view) {
    EditText guessedName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.authorIs);
    String guessedNameString = guessedName.getText().toString();
    int guessNameInt = Integer.parseInt(guessedNameString);
    int whoSaidItInt = Integer.parseInt(whoSaidIt);

    if (guessNameInt == whoSaidItInt) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Holy crow, Good job!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    randomNum = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
}`
```

Comment: without the stacktrace, it's hard to say, but it's pretty weird that you're trying to convert a string (guessedNameString) to an int (a number). So, if you type 'Albert Einstein', and you convert it to an int, the Java code will throw an error. The solution? Don't convert it to an int :-) The solution would probably involve comparing the string, so if you do that, please use .equals, not ==. Just google for it.

Comment: You keep setting the name to a string `whoSaidIt = "Rick";` but then you try to parse it for an integer `Integer.parseInt(whoSaidIt);`. This isn't going to work

Comment: Post ([edit]) your Logcat

Comment: ohmygod filter the logcat for your application

Comment: I'm not sure why you post the Logcat, I think the answer is pretty clear, but the log contains the error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "Jerry" at `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to convert a String to an Int. This will only work if the String is an actual int (ie a number), and not the name (Jerry or Rick). Use `guessNameString.equals(whoSaidIt)` instead.

Comment: In this exact code 'guessedNameString' should be used, otherwise the equation is always false because of different classes

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Comment: Thanks so much! This definitely stopped it from crashing. however, now it says "try again" even if its right. but i may be able to figure this one out.

Comment: YOU GUYS ARE HEROS! The answer i needed was already posted above^ i hadn't changed the guessName to a string, but when i did it worked great!! Thanks so much!